# When does the Bertrand paradox apply?

Tags: probability, paradoxes

[Link to Wikipedia article on the Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))

There's [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657076/whats-the-probability-of-choosing-two-numbers-from-0-1-and-having-the-differe) asked recently that superficially looks like Bertrand's paradox. Both involve picking random points/chords and then calculating a property. Yet one leads to a not-well-defined situation, while the other apparently has a well-defined answer of 0.25.

Why? How does one tell if a question is well-defined or if Bertrand's paradox will apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Bertrand's paradox is that you must properly specify the probability model for a "random" object in order to get a unique correct answer.  In the "other" question you refer to, although the model is not
quite explicitly specified there is an obvious choice: $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution uniform on the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.  Therefore there is no paradox here.  But if somebody wanted, say, $X^2$ and $Y^2$ rather than $X$ and $Y$ to be uniform, they would get a different answer.